# How do I create a docker container with two Java applications and Mysql server?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have a Java application consuming binlogs from Mysql database and interacting with another service which I have hosted on my localhost. How do I create a Docker image with all these services so that I can run them all at once?

From what I've heard, I need to use docker-compose. But I don't really know how to?
Do I create separate Docker containers and link their ports?
Do I create one container?

I have created one Dockerfile for the Java application:

```
FROM maslick/minimalka:jdk11
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/foster-maxwell-uber-jar.jar foster-maxwell.jar
COPY config.properties config.properties
CMD java -jar foster-maxwell.jar --config_type MAXWELL_UNSIGNED_KAAS --kaas_config config.yml --zk_timeout 1000
```

How do I go about it? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Yes you will want multiple docker containers, one for each process. And use docker compose to link them all together in same network.

Answer (score 0):

You should read docker-compose documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

For example, try with a **docker-compose.yml** file like this

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  your-java-app1:
    build:
      context: .          <-- (dir where you have your Dockerfile)
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: yourjavaapp1image:1.0
    container_name: your-java-app1
    depends_on:
      - db

  your-java-app2:
    build:
      context: .          <-- (dir where you have your Dockerfile_for_app2)
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_for_app2
    image: yourjavaapp2image:1.0
    container_name: your-java-app2
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: [put here your root pass]
       MYSQL_DATABASE: [put here your db name]
       MYSQL_USER: [put here your user]
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: [put here your pass]
```

Once you have this defined your Dockerfiles, first, build images with your apps:

```
docker-compose build
```

Then, run images (container creations)

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness it should be mentioned that is is possible to create custom image with multiple services inside: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/. It's just usually a really bad idea, as it's harder to maintain and to upgrade individual services.